# Laravel 5.2: After login the app lost session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying fix this for one entire day, searching many times and many ways in Google.

After I enter my username and password I get a 401 Unauthorized, but in the /storage/framework/session the file is created.

Login page parts

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

...

<form class="login-form" action="admin/login" method="post">
                <h3 class="form-title">Access Data</h3>
                <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
                    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                    <span>
                    Username or password invalid. </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
                    <label for="username" class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"/> Remember me </label>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn blue pull-right">
                    Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
            </form>

...

<script>
            $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                data = $('form').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'url': 'admin/login',
                    'data': data,
                    'dataType': 'JSON',
                    'success': function (data) {
                        if (data.type === 'redirect') {
                            window.location.href = 'admin/dashboard';
                        } else {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

In the end of jquery.min file

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

Route.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('admin', ['uses' => 'UsersController@getLogin']);
        Route::post('admin/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@doLogin']);
        Route::post('admin/logout', ['uses' => 'UsersController@doLogout']);
    //});
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    //Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('admin/dashboard', function() {
            return view('admin/dashboard');
        });
    //});
});
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request, Validator, Redirect, Hash, Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Models\UsersAuth;
use App\Models\UsersModel;

class UsersController extends Controller {
    function getLogin() {
        return view('admin/index');
    }

    function doLogin() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:5'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            /*...*/
        } else {
            if(Auth::attempt(['username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => '1'])) {
                if(Auth::check()) {
                    return json_encode(['type' => 'redirect']);
                }
            } else {
                return json_encode(['type' => 'danger', 'msg' => 'Username or password is invalid.']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\UsersAuth::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
    | that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
    | table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

UsersAuth.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class UsersAuth extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
    * Users db table.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = '002';

    /**
    * URL to redirect after login.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And laravel.log is empty ('debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)).

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Check the response you get from the ajax request, does it contain a session cookie?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in the Laravel 5.2. how can I check Ajax Requests and the session cookies?

Comment: If I use "Request $request" argument in the doLogin function I get the "TokenMismatchException" error in laravel.log, and browser console code 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

After two days searching for a solution I think in changing all database columns to default name like id, username, password, etc (before I was using 002_id, 002_username, 002_password, etc...)...
After changes everything is working fine.

In Laravel you dosen't have the option to use your custom fields without mod the base Auth class? O.o
And for what is this errors without information? Like "TokenMismatchException"...

Comment: It's easy check downvote without a better solution, without change class base code.

Comment: You can change the primary key that your model uses using the $primaryKey property (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't made to many changes, try running `php artisan make:auth` again.